# Xcode automatically perform build opertaion

Tags: ios, xcode

I am facing unexpected issue with Xcode 9.0. Even if I am writing code in the app, Xcode automatically performs build operation. See below image

[image]

Even I deleted derived data, restarts Xcode and System but issue is the same. Because of this my system in getting slow down.

Can anyone suggest how should I stop this build operation.

Please let me know if I have explain my question more.

Comment: try to update xcode 9.1

Answer (score 1):

When Live issues setting enabled it will come like that. Please turn it off by following below.

Please do this step:

Go to **Preferences** -> **General** and disable **Live Issues** in Editors and in Issue Navigator

Talking about this in case if you won't understand

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its happen because of automatic refresh of IBDesignable. For this goto Storyboard -> Menu **Editor** -> **Automatically Refresh View** just uncheck it . It will work fine.